# Extra condition in rollup output "iife"

Tags: javascript, iife, svelte, rollupjs

For the following `rollup.config`:

```js
module.exports = {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: {
        file: "dist/bundle.js",
        sourcemap: true,
        format: "iife",
        name: "MySvelteApp"
    },
    ...
};
```

rollup correctly generates:

```js
var MySvelteApp = (function () {
 ...
}());
```

However I would like to add an extra conditional check:

```js
var MySvelteApp = !MySvelteApp && (function () {
 ...
}());
```

such that code from within MySvelteApp doesn't accidentally get run twice. Any ideas on how to customize the config?

Comment: I am 99% sure you don't want to do this. See, when MySvelteApp is already defined, it will be set to `false` instead.

Comment: i don't really care about its value - the only thing i need to make sure of is its contents don't get executed on every load of the script

Comment: Why would the script get loaded multiple times?

Comment: Still, if you do this your function will run every second time (at least if it returns something)

Comment: What you are looking for is something like `var MySvelteApp = MySvelteApp || (function() { ... }());`